# Does does turning into the wind increase airspeed and/or climb rate?

Tags: aircraft-performance, flight-dynamics

At 5:24 to 6:10 in the video linked below, Kelsey appears to be claiming that turning into the wind tends to create 1) an increase in *airspeed* and 2) and an increase in climb *rate*.  Are either of these claims accurate?

Since Kelsey didn't say anything about the wind *gradient*, consider the case where the wind gradient is negligible, i.e. the case where the wind speed and direction are nearly constant over the altitude range of interest.

The case where the wind gradient is *not* negligible may be of some interest as well.  Though if the aircraft's vertical speed is *very low*, this would tend to suggest that even a significant wind gradient would have minimal effect on the aircraft's actual performance.

Comment: PS-- consider-- if you were actually at risk of *sinking lower*-- and there *was* a significant wind gradient-- which direction of flight, with respect to the wind, would minimize the *sink rate*?

Comment: A headwind doesn’t affect *rate* of climb (feet per minute) because your airspeed doesn’t change, but it will increase the *angle* of climb (feet per mile) due to the reduced ground speed.

Comment: Why are you dragging out this dead horse again?  Other than the video link to this specific snippet of commentary, the subject has been covered here in many other questions.  Nothing new here, and I'd vote to close as a dupe, but the system will force me to search for a specific dupe...

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/54983/60584